# Difference between licensed and demo Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, demo

I'm using demo Kendo UI on my local about 6 months. When I published my application, I referenced licensed `dll`. But I didn't see any difference between them. I 've searched a bit, and I saw only additionally support tickets.

Can anyone tell me what is difference?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Licensing and then should be address by Kendo UI support / commercial department.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for one there is the fact that according to the license agreement:

> If You download the free Trial License, then, subject to the terms and conditions set forth in this agreement, Licensor hereby grants to Licensee and Licensee hereby accepts a license to use the Software for the sole purpose of evaluating its functionality and performance. You are not allowed to integrate the Software into end products or use it for any commercial, productive or training purpose. You may not redistribute the Software. The term of the Trial License shall be 30 days. If You wish to continue using the Software beyond expiration of the Trial License, You must purchase the applicable commercial license.
>
> You are also eligible for all major and minor updates with a commercial license. With a trial license you are not eligible for major updates and you may get minor updates at Telerik's discretion. There are also changes in support between a trial and a commercial license